# SwiftUI how to avoid delay() during the reversing state of an animation?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to implement a simple loading animation using SwiftUI. The animation logic is as follows:

1. Enlarge the first circle, then return it to its original size.
2. Enlarge the second circle, then return it to its original size.
3. Enlarge the third circle, then return it to its original size.
4. Repeat steps 1-3 indefinitely.

However, I have noticed that if I use repeatForever(autoreverses: true) with delay(), there is an unwanted delay when the animation is played in reverse. How can I avoid this delay during the reverse animation?

```
import SwiftUI

struct AnimationView: View {
    @State private var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State var animate = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Circle()
                .scaleEffect(scale)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1.0).delay(0).repeatForever(autoreverses: true), value: animate)
            Circle()
                .scaleEffect(scale)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1.0).delay(1).repeatForever(autoreverses: true), value: animate)
            Circle()
                .scaleEffect(scale)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1.0).delay(2).repeatForever(autoreverses: true), value: animate)
        }
        .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
        .onAppear {
            animate = true
            scale = 1.2
        }
    }
}



struct AnimationView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AnimationView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to move .delay() after repeatForever

```
.repeatForever(autoreverses: true).delay(2)
```

also you can improve to avoid code duplication

```
struct AnimationView: View {
@State private var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
@State var animate = false

let startTimes: [Double] = [1, 1.5, 2] // Start times for each circle animation

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        ForEach(0..<startTimes.count, id: \.self) { index in
            Circle()
                .scaleEffect(scale)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)
                    .repeatForever(autoreverses: true)
                    .delay(startTimes[index]), value: animate)
        }
    }
    .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
    .onAppear {
        animate = true
        scale = 1.2
    }
} }
```